# Can't understand how to perform Segue from my custom Cell (in UICollectionView) to Player (ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, collectionview

Hi dear professionals.

I have main **ViewController**, where I put **Three horizontal CollectionView** with cells into (but I hope at least solve problem with 1 of these).

One of this named - **FirstPlaylistCollectionView**
Cells also custom - **FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell**

On tap on cell with specific video it needed pass **Video** object to the **Player** (**PlayerViewController**).

I cant figure it out how, in my case, make this **Segue** (pass Video object with necessary data) from **CollectionView** by code !
I almost don't use Storyboard in this project.

Maybe with help of **Delegate**, but I'm also couldn't understand how to use them for my case.

Method **didSelectItemAt** - works and get Video object, but i don't understand how to pass it correctly.

Will be very grateful for answer. I couldn't apply for now any solution from Stack, help please.

**FirstPlaylistCollectionView code**

```
import UIKit

protocol FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func playVideo()
}



class FirstPlaylistCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, ModelDelegate {

  var playlistsModel = PlaylistsModel()

  private var firstPlaylist: [Video] = []

  weak var delegate2: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate?



// MARK: - Data Source

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return firstPlaylist.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell
    
    let video = self.firstPlaylist[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(video)
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    self.delegate2?.playVideo()
   
    print("selected video \(firstPlaylist[indexPath.row]) with \(collectionView)! DONE!")
    
}
```

**FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell code**

```
class FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

static let reuseId = "FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell"

var video: Video?
```

**PlayerViewController code**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var handleArea: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var openCloseArrow: UIImageView!

    var video: Video?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    print("I'm here!!!")
    
    let vc2 = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
    if let cell = sender as? Video {
        self.video = cell
        vc2.titleOfVideoLabel.text = video?.title
    }
    }

}

extension PlayerViewController: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate {
   func playVideo() {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToPlayer", sender: self)
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to launch `PlayerViewController` from `ViewController` by passing `Video`  to it?

Comment: Actually I need this too @JayachandraA, yes. But not this way. Do you have idea about that ?

Comment: @JayachandraA I will upvote your answer if yes. Maybe link. Thanks in advance

Comment: And one more thing, your `FirstPlaylistCollectionView` is in your `ViewConroller` and taken `IBOutlet` right?

Comment: @JayachandraA Yes!) But I almost don’t use IBOutlets. I make simple var and connect it by addSubview. 
IBOutlets I have only Dots (PageControl) :)

Comment: So, programmatically you have added your collection view in side the ViewController ?

Comment: @JayachandraA Yes yes, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this by assuming some of the things, I hope you want to navigate to `PlayerViewController` from `ViewController` through a segue. Keeping that in my mind, I have assumed your `FirstPlaylistCollectionView` is in your `ViewController` class as mentioned below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var firstPlaylistCollectionView: FirstPlaylistCollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // First try to get notified from your collection list to here
        // and then from here to your player
        firstPlaylistCollectionView.listDelegate = self
    }
    
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let id = segue.identifier, id == "playerSegue",
            let lVideo = sender as? Video,
            let destination = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController{
            destination.video = lVideo
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate {
    func firstPlaylistCollectionView(_ listView: FirstPlaylistCollectionView, didSlect video: Video) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "playerSegue", sender: video)
    }
}
```

And below is the update for the collection view

```
class FirstPlaylistCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  var playlistsModel = PlaylistsModel()
  private var firstPlaylist: [Video] = []
  weak var listDelegate: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate?
}

extension FirstPlaylistCollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return firstPlaylist.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! FirstPlaylistCollectionViewCell
        /* Here it goes your cell configuration
         .
         .
         */
        
        return cell
    }
}

extension FirstPlaylistCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        listDelegate?.firstPlaylistCollectionView(self, didSlect: firstPlaylist[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

And finally verify that the playerViewController has received the data or not

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var handleArea: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var openCloseArrow: UIImageView!
    var video: Video?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Video object from player vc :: \(video)")
    }
}
```

Added protocol is

```
protocol FirstPlaylistCollectionViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func firstPlaylistCollectionView(_ listView: FirstPlaylistCollectionView, didSlect video: Video) ->Void
}
```

Comment: U are very cool !!!!

Comment: It is very important that you wrote this with explanations and comments !!! Great thanks !!! I will return to this project within a week. If questions come up, I will write it here, and thanks one more time

Answer (score 0):

you can use Prepare for segue or Did Select Row method try these out.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedProgram = programy[indexPath.row]
    let destinationVC = PlayerTableViewController()
    destinationVC.programVar = selectedProgram

    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: No no, I have CollectionView, not Table ! This is the same solution?

Comment: It says Receiver (<YoutubeAPI.PlayerViewController: 0x7f95638e8200>) has no segue with identifier 'playerSegue'